# A deep justification for or against different meta-categories of tags

Tags: discussion, tags

I'm looking for perspectives coming from deep within Stack Exchange moderation theory, and information science and categorization systems with a focus on human factors, usability, and user experience.

It does appear that Meta sites have different meta-categories of tags - there are straightforward subject tags, which is, "what is this post about" (comments, moderation, etc.), and there is sort of a second level of tags, "discussion", "feature-request", "support". Maybe we could say this is more like, what kind of interaction is this post looking for.

But back on a normal stack exchange site, I am not sure if the idea of different kinds of tags has been recognized. It may exist implicitly on some sites. One example is, we definitely have subject tags like "epistemology", but we also appear to have some more "use"-like tags, like "reference-request". Stating the obvious, but "reference-request"-tagged questions are not about the philosophical topic of "the nature of requesting references", they are posts themselves which are actually requesting references on some topic.

One reason I bring this up is because I wonder if the tag "definitions" hasn't been assessed as to what its intended use is. It could very well be about the philosophical topic of definitions. It may also be used thus far as a way of classifying questions which are seeking a definition of something (which is arguably one of the most perennial motivating forces insofar as there is any field known as "philosophy": what is art, what is love, what is time, what is nature, etc.) Then I think we could do well to split that into two tags. Thus, we would have a "use"-tag, asking for a good definition of something.

https://philosophy.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/definitions